# Azure Table Storage Concurrency Issue

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-table-storage, optimistic-concurrency

It seems like concurrency conflicts with Azure throw an exception with a message containing the error code 412. Is there a good way to tell that an exception is thrown due to a concurrency problem other than checking if the error message of a StorageException contains 412 in the message? This seems like a really stringly typed approach.

Comment: See http://razingtheivorytower.blogspot.com/2012/09/optimistic-concurrency-with-azure-tables.html.  You can check for `StatusCode = 412`, which is still a magic number, but not matching error strings.

Comment: Ah I missed that. If you want to throw the link in an answer I'll accept it. It's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode seems to work for me

```
    try
    {
        TableOperation operation = TableOperation.Merge(ent);
        retval = await table.ExecuteAsync(operation);
    }
    catch (StorageException sex)
    {
        if (sex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed)
        {
            TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<BotSetting>(ent.PartitionKey, ent.RowKey);
            TableResult retrievedResult = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
            if (retrievedResult.Result != null)
            {
                BotSetting bs = retrievedResult.Result as BotSetting;
                retval = await TryMerge(table, bs, tries--);
            }
        }
    }
```